# How come one of my segues isn't working?

Tags: swift, function, segue, viewcontroller

I am developing a quiz app and when you answer a question correctly it segues to one view controller and if you press the wrong answer it segues to another view controller. However when I run the simulator, if I click on a wrong answer nothing happens except the countdown timer resets. However if I click the right answer then that segues works just fine. Why is this?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var questionList = [String]()
    var counter = 15
    var timer = Timer()
    var rightAnswerBox:UInt32 = 0
    var index = 0

    //Question Label
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var questionTimer: UILabel!


    func updateCounter() {
        counter -= 1
        questionTimer.text = String(counter)

        if counter == 0 {


            timer.invalidate()
            wrongSeg()
        }
    }

    func randomQuestion() {

        //random question
        if questionList.isEmpty {
            questionList = Array(QADictionary.keys)
        }

        let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questionList.count)))
        questionLabel.text = questionList[rand]


        //matching answer values to go with question keys
        var choices = QADictionary[questionList[rand]]!

        questionList.remove(at: rand)

        //create button
        var button:UIButton = UIButton()

        //variables
        var x = 1
        rightAnswerBox = arc4random_uniform(4)+1


        for index in 1...4
        {
            button = view.viewWithTag(index) as! UIButton

            if (index == Int(rightAnswerBox))
            {
                button.setTitle(choices[0], for: .normal)

            }

            else {
                button.setTitle(choices[x], for: .normal)
                x += 1

            }
        }

        randomImage()

    }

    //dictionary filled with question keys and answer values
    let QADictionary = [:]


    //wrong view segue
    func wrongSeg() {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "incorrectSeg", sender: self)

    }

    //proceed screen
    func rightSeg() {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "correctSeg", sender: self)
    }

    //Answer Button
    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        if (sender.tag == Int(rightAnswerBox)) {

            rightSeg()
            timer.invalidate()
            print ("Correct!")
        }

        if counter != 0 {

            counter = 15

        } else if (sender.tag != Int(rightAnswerBox)) {

            wrongSeg()
            print ("Wrong!")
            timer.invalidate()
            questionList = []

        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        randomQuestion()

        questionTimer.text = String(counter)
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target:self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
}
```

Comment: Provide an image of your storyboard showing the segue

Comment: @DharmeshKheni how do I share the project on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put wrong condition inside buttonAction i have corrected it check now. just replace else if condiotion

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        if (sender.tag == Int(rightAnswerBox)) {

            rightSeg()
            timer.invalidate()
            print ("Correct!")
        }/*Here is change*/
      else if (sender.tag != Int(rightAnswerBox)) 
       {

            wrongSeg()
            print ("Wrong!")
            timer.invalidate()
            questionList = []

        }
        if counter != 0 {

            counter = 15

        } 
    }
```